# Using predict at sample means on a binary variable

Tags: r, binary-data, predict

Something quite common in regression is to try and predict the outcome at the sample mean.

This is complicated when there are binary independent variables; the typical approach is the plug in sample percentages to the associated coefficients, like so:

```
set.seed(102349)
x = runif(1e3) > .73
y = 6 - 3.4 * x + rnorm(1e3)
reg <- lm(y ~ x)
```

The sample average of x is about .27 by construction, so to get the predicted `y` associated with the "typical" observation, we plug in `.27` for the coefficient on `xTRUE`:

```
sum(reg$coefficients * c(1, mean(x)))
# [1] 5.032203
```

This is cumbersome and obtuse in more complicated models, however. Is there any way to get `predict` to work for such a model?

This is an error, since `lm` keeps track of the classes it was supplied:

```
predict(reg, data.frame(x = mean(x)))
```

I was able to trick `predict` to work like so, but it seems inadvisable to overwrite the original model object like this:

```
#surprise, predict! it's not logical after all!
attr(reg$terms, "dataClasses")["x"] <- "numeric"

#and because it's not logical, there are no contrasts either!
reg$contrasts <- NULL

#try and complain now, chump!
predict(reg, data.frame(x = mean(x)))
#        1 
# 5.032203
```